# How to get a table's data in couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I'm very new to couchdb so my question may seem very simple; I'm using [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) to connect to my couchdb; I have read most of the [documentation](https://github.com/dscape/nano), however I couldn't figure out how I can get all of the data in a table? What is the syntax to get all of the data of a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [this article](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html) useful.

To get all of the documents in a database, you can use the [_all_docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html) API endpoint, which nano wraps in its' [db.list](https://github.com/dscape/nano#dblistparams-callback) method.

```
mydb.list(function(err, body) {
  if (!err) {
    body.rows.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting; nano.db.list; lists all of tables, whereas foo.list lists all of the documents in foo table,...

Answer (score 1):

To get all the docs in a current database you'd request the [`/{db}/_all_docs` endpoint](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#post--db-_all_docs).

Nano wraps that endpoint in two separate functions: `listDoc` and `fetchDocs`. See the code for [nano.js](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/e04872746609083ef6c6eb55d1abdb1aadb43b39/lib/nano.js#L438-L464). These functions are [exported on the `db` object as `list` and `fetch`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano/blob/e04872746609083ef6c6eb55d1abdb1aadb43b39/lib/nano.js#L690-L691).

- `list` will get you the ID's of all the docs in the database.
- `fetch` will include the docs themselves in the result--which if you're building a backup system or similar is probably what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that `nano` is now part of the Apache CouchDB project: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano That's the better one to use going forward--as it replaces the original, older one.